# Add a decimal point between two pulled xpath values using IMPORTXML in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

Gday!

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to figure out how to add a decimal point between two pulled xpath values for the purpose of comparing local supermarket prices.

I've managed to pull the two values (cents and dollars) from (for example) https://www.newworld.co.nz/shop/product/5011024_ea_000nw?name=chicken-crimpy-crackers but what it's doing is putting the two values into one number - in this case, 249. How am I able to add a decimal point to make it $2.49? ('$' isn't necessary but would be nice). Here is what I have so far:

```
=JOIN("",IMPORTXML("https://www.newworld.co.nz/shop/product/5011024_ea_000nw?name=chicken-crimpy-","//span[@class='fs-price-lockup__dollars' or @class='fs-price-lockup__cents']"))*1
```

If there's something that I can add or I'm missing a feature Google Sheets has, if someone could let me know, that would be amazing! This is my first time creating a spreadsheet for anything so I have a wee bit to learn :)

Any questions or I'm missing crucial info, let me know and I'd be happy to help where I can.

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatinate `$` sign with the jointed result of the `IMPORTXML`
And the use `TEXTJOIN` to join the array {2;49} into 2.49 with a dot `.` as a delimiter.

```
="$"&TEXTJOIN(".",1,
     IMPORTXML(
      "https://www.newworld.co.nz/shop/product/5011024_ea_000nw?name=chicken-crimpy-",
      "//span[@class='fs-price-lockup__dollars' or @class='fs-price-lockup__cents']"))
```

[image]

Comment: Legend! That works perfectly. Thanks heaps mate, really appreciate it